# How should i unwrap this mesh so the texture won't stretch at edges?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

[image][image]so this is supposed to be a speaker grid ( I'm using texturing instead of modeling it), the problem that it's stretching around these curved edges, I don't know how to wrap it the right way yet.

Thank you so much, your help is much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried the smart uv unwrap method? Do you require the perfection of hand unwrapped UVs ?

Comment: yes i tried that and didn't work, no I'm a beginner i used to unwrapped uvs of simpler meshes but this one is a bit more complicated for me

Comment: could you please share your file with its image packed inside? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: You can try the smart UV unwrap if that doesn't solve the problem then you can go to the top view and unwrap the mesh by selecting the top faces and clicking `project from view`and then you can unwrap the side faces seperately.

Comment: Thank you all so much for trying to help, I managed to make it finally using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHbgQs8zkpw 
I'll leave it here in case it could be useful for anybody else